# Removing Variables

Tags: java, variables

my work says to Remove the r, c and e variables from this how would I do this

```
Rectangle  r = new Rectangle(10 * iFrame, 10 * iFrame, 50, 50); r.draw(gcw);
  
Circle c= new Circle(200, 300 - iFrame*5, 100); c.draw(gcw);
  
Ellipse e = new Ellipse(150, 300, 90 + iFrame, 160); e.draw(gcw);
```

Comment: By "remove", they probably mean "inline". e.g. `new Rectangle(...params).draw(gcw);`. If you're using intelliJ you get this functionality for free by highlighting the expression and pressing something like `⌘⌥N` (or ctrl + alt + N)

Comment: **1**. Determine the purpose of these variables.  **2**. See if syntax allows to calculate their values *in-line*.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke `draw(..)` on the object returned by the constructor without assigning it to a variable.  You are still creating an object - you just aren't assigning it to a variable so you can access it elsewhere.

```
new Rectangle(10 * iFrame, 10 * iFrame, 50, 50).draw(gcw);
new Circle(200, 300 - iFrame*5, 100).draw(gcw);
new Ellipse(150, 300, 90 + iFrame, 160).draw(gcw);
```